# Difference between elasticsearch ReIndex task REST API implementation and Java rest high level client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I'm trying to use elastic search reindex api via rest high level client and am comparing two ways of doing it.
Rest API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api
[![Rest API Documentation screenshot][1]][1]
`Running reindex asynchronously - If the request contains wait_for_completion=false, Elasticsearch performs some preflight checks, launches the request, and returns a task you can use to cancel or get the status of the task. Elasticsearch creates a record of this task as a document at _tasks/<task_id>. When you are done with a task, you should delete the task document so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space.`
rest high level client：
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-reindex.html#java-rest-high-document-reindex-task-submission
[![rest high level client Documentation screenshot][2]][2]
`Reindex task submission - It is also possible to submit a ReindexRequest and not wait for it completion with the use of Task API. This is an equivalent of a REST request with wait_for_completion flag set to false.`

I'm trying to figure out this: From Rest API Doc I know that I should delete the task document so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space. Since the rest high level client is basically doing the same thing, do I need to "delete the task document" if I choose to use this client instead of the rest API? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEVHi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw9Dw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task document is just a summary of what happen during reindex (so a small document), since you specify to do in async with `wait_for_completion=false` it will be created in system indice `.tasks`, so you can query this indice like any other to find the summary and delete it.

The `.tasks` indice will not be available by default in futur version of Elasticsearch and you will need to use specific function linked to `_tasks` with the java REST api available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-tasks-list.html)